# How to use POST API of wordpress.com to post a blog using Axios in React App?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, post, axios

Following is my PostHandler, where I am trying to post a blog from my React App but I am getting status code `405`.

```
postBlogHandler = () => {
    const post = {
        title: this.state.title,
        content: this.state.content,
        author: this.state.author
    }
    axios.post('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.2/sites/ishhaanpatel.wordpress.com/posts/new', post)
    .then( response  => {
        console.log(response);
    } );
}
```

And following was the response.

> {"error":"unauthorized","message":"That method is not allowed."}

Is there a guide online that we can learn from how to use different APIs and master sending different HTTP requests and handling Response?

Comment: Its seems that you need to something like an access oder session token to post on this ressource.

Comment: I believe you need some authentication headers to make requests to the Wordpress API. Trying reading through this documention: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to include API token argument with the API endpoint.